# EF Core : one table references another table twice

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-core

```
public class DialogueEntry
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("Take")]
    public int? MasterTakeId { get; set; }

    public Take MasterTake { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Take> Takes { get; set; }
}

public class Take
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DialogueEntry")]
    public int DialogueEntryId { get; set; }

    public DialogueEntry DialogueEntry { get; set; }
}
```

I get this error:

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'DialogueEntry.MasterTake' of type 'Take'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

I am trying to configure a one-to-many relationship between `DialogueEntry` and `Take`. `DialogueEntry` has a one-to-one reference to the `Take` table which is the `MasterTake` property, and if without adding the one-to-many navigation line, everything works fine.

When I added the `ICollection` property, I get the error message shown.

Comment: MasterTakeId is not neccessary. Entity Framework itself creates this foreign key during migration. Can you try removing this ID and trying again.

Comment: I didnt understant why it is not neccessary, I need this MasterTakeID to determine which Take entry will be highlighted if that make sense.

Comment: `modelBuilder.Entity<DialogueEntry>()
        .HasOne(d => d.MasterTake)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.MasterTakeId);


    modelBuilder.Entity<Take>()
        .HasOne(t => t.DialogueEntry)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(t => t.DialogueEntryId);`

This situation seems to be related to Fluent API. Please try this in OnModelCreating override method in your Context class.